# angular.js ng-focus and ng-bind expressions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, focus, expression, blur

I would like to know when an *input* element is active, to achieve this I thought about the `ng-focus` and `ng-blur` directives, but these directives won't work...
Here I have a jsFiddle example, why it doesn't work?

http://jsfiddle.net/TgNae/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**ng-blur** was added in 1.2.0, and your example uses 1.1.1. If you use [this](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0rc1/angular.js) version instead of current, it works just fine.